# How to select related rows from another table in extra() method of Django queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have two simple models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    text = models.Textfield()
    writer = models.Foreignkey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.Textfield()
    submitted_by = models.Foreignkey(User)
    which_blog = models.Foreignkey(Blog)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Essentially, users can submit a blog object, and other users can leave comments under the said blog object.

Next, I want to append the **timestamp of the latest comment**, to each blog object. Note that I don't want to append the global maximum timestamp from the entire Comment table - rather, only the latest time from all comments *that have the said blog object as a foreignkey*. I.e. nothing gets appended for blogs that don't have any comments.

I'm unable to formulate a query for the above. Here's what I'm trying:

```
blog_qset = Blog.objects.extra(select={'date':"SELECT max(date) FROM appname_comment WHERE appname_comment.which_blog_id=%s"},select_params=(blog.id,),)
```

This simply appends a globally max timestamp to each blog object, instead of looking for a max *only from related rows of the comment table*. Please help me sanitize the SQL query inside extra(), as per the requirements I described in the big paragraph above.

*Note: For reasons outside the scope of this question, I can't use annotate() to accomplish this task.*

Comment: Can you post your full traceback, along with what the `blog` variable contains?

Comment: By `blog`, I'm trying to reference the specific instance of the Blog class that the extra method may be iterating over. It hasn't been formally initialized (it's probably the wrong way to do this). What would be the correct SQL query to accomplish my requirements, sans `blog`?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
blog_qset = Blog.objects.extra(select={'date':"SELECT max(date) FROM appname_comment WHERE appname_comment.which_blog_id=%s"},select_params=(blog.id,),)
```

Comment: Anush, that gets rid of the syntax error, but simply appends a global timestamp to all blog posts. We'll probably need to rework that query.

Comment: I changed the question's wording a bit to reflect this.